# How can I create a new VM from captured image (snapshot)?

Tags: azure

I captured a VM image and tried to create new vm from the captured image. But I got an error. (Linux, using azure cli)

```
$ azure vm generalize [Resource Group] [VM Name]
$ azure vm capture [Resource Group] [VM Name]

info:    vm capture command OK

$ azure vm create \
      --image-urn [osDisk:image url] \
      --resource-group [Resource Group] \
      --name [New VM Name] \
      --storage-account-name XYZ \
      --location xxx \
      --os-type Linux \
      --admin-username xxx \
      --admin-password xxx \
      --nic-names xxx \
      --vm-size xxx

[Storage Account Name] is not a valid storage account name. Storage account name must be between 3 and 24 characters in length and use numbers and lower-case letters only.
```

I have 2 questions:

(1) How can I avoid the error. I don't think I set the storage account name. I set XYZ but the error showed another name.

(2) I got two vm images link after vm capture: osDisk:image and osDisk:vhd. Which one should I use when I create a new VM?

```
resources: [
      {
      apiVersion: '2016-03-30',
      properties: {
      storageProfile: {
      osDisk: {
        image: { uri: 'https://XXX.vhd' },
        vhd: { uri: 'https://XXX.vhd' },
      caching: 'ReadWrite'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ad1. Storage name can consist of only lower case letters, try with xyz.

Ad2. osDisk.image is the path to the image from which you want to deploy VM, while osDisk.vhd is the path to the newly created machine's disk.